# From where does task manager pull metrics for GPU and CPU?

Tags: c#, windows, gpu, wmi, taskmanager

I have been trying to get details from WMI to be able to replicate the [task manager tabs for GPU metrics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEI6j.png)

I have settled on the following WMI classes to get some details which are shown in the

- `\\<machine-name>\ROOT\CIMV2:Win32_VideoController` for the [driver details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsI8k.png)
- `\\<device-name>\ROOT\CIMV2:Win32_PerfFormattedData_GPUPerformanceCounters_GPUEngine` for the [GPU utilization information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adLee.png)
- `\\<machine-name>\ROOT\CIMV2:Win32_PerfFormattedData_GPUPerformanceCounters_GPUAdapterMemory` class for the shared and dedicated memory utilization

However, the last 2 classes mentioned do not provide the metrics mapped to a named GPU identifier. Instead these are mapped to a LUID

I am still not sure where Task Manager gets the details for the Total Dedicated Memory as I have not found any class or property exposing the same reliably. I know the total shared memory is calculated as `TotalPhysicalMemory/2`

**Where is Task Manager getting all these data and how is it mapping it to the particular GPU (As there can be multiple GPUs in a machine)?**

I have come across a blog post that tells how some of the metrics are calculated, but it does not say where the date is captured from:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/directx/gpus-in-the-task-manager/

Comment: The Taskmanager is known for using undocumented functions, you might have to debug it...

Comment: Hi @Anders, any idea how can I go about this?

Comment: Use a strings tool or a debugger

Answer (score -1):

GPU and CPU speeds can be accessed by using Perfmon (performance counters). You can speed information, read/write etc.,.. It is also an alternative to using WMI.

However, the CPU and GPU are also dependent on the vendor. Which means if the manufacturer has not released documentation you will not be able to accurately pull the information needed.

Take temperature for example. Many vendors keep the documentation non existent to developers, some vendors welcome the development on documentation.

So it boils down to the information you want versus what is available. Most CPU and GPU information is limited and depends on the vendor.

I ran into this a few years back with the CPU temp. I could get the temp from one PC and not another. Found out it relies on the vendor and disclosure.

Basic information you can get as percentage, read/write and so forth. So be sure to see documentation for vendors and you may have to make a list of different vendors that shows which has access and which doesn't.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. The windows Taskmanager displays this information in a seemingly vendor agnostic way, and that's what OP wants to replicate.

Comment: @istepaniuk it answered perfectly.. that's why the term "use Perfmon" was the first thing mentioned.. I have been dealing with WMI for 10 years plus build real world applications that use WMI. He wants to simulate task manager then he will have to use Perfmon. However a lot of what he can get depends on what the manufacturer allows to be accessed.

Comment: Hi @CampNerd, thanks for the answer. I know about perfmon, and that is how I narrowed my search down to the WMI classes mentioned above (but running benchmark tests and observing the changes in perfmon). But even in perfmon, if you open the counters, it does not show the name of the GPU to which the metrics are ties. They mention everything via LUIDs. I was looking for something at a code level (like an API) which would provide these details