# windows game bar -> performance widget -> any api to get the same values?

Tags: c#, windows

What are the API to get the same indicators of the performance widget through the windows game bar?

[the widget I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1eCM.png)

I'm writing a background service which sends my computer usages to a port com.

Have a good day.

Comment: Very likely, your problem can be solved using WMI - see [From where does task manager pull metrics for GPU and CPU?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73219395/205233) and other existing questions.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @IkramAkbar I want to fetch CPU use, GPU use, RAM use, VRAM use, FPS from a windows computer. I'm currently working with OpenHardwareMonitor DLL. But I'am asking if someone know how and where the windows game bar fetches data on their side.